# What is the JSON format for a firestore composite index including an array?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to filter a collection (let's call it `documents`) using `array-contains` on one column (say `keywords`) and sort by another column (say `name`).

I am able to create this composite index in the firebase console, but I can only guess at the format for adding it to `firestore.indexes.json`.

It's unfortunate we can't download the index file from the console.

Answer (score 58):

Set the mode to ARRAY_CONTAINS:

```
{
      "collectionId": "documents",
      "fields": [
        {
          "fieldPath": "keywords",
          "mode": "ARRAY_CONTAINS"
        },
        {
          "fieldPath": "name",
          "mode": "ASCENDING"
        }
  ]
}
```

You can also [list your current Cloud Firestore indexes](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools#cloud-firestore-commands) in JSON from the Firebase CLi:

```
firebase firestore:indexes
```

Comment: Awesome, wish I could give you points for each part. I would have guessed ARRAY from the console, and my second guess would have been ARRAY-CONTAINS from the API.

Comment: Nice job for adding the firebase command to download the index file from the CLI!

Comment: For me this when exporting collection group indexes this is exporting a bad formatter json. The command line forget to close the array notifier on indexes:

Comment: M. V. P.

You would thinking googling would make it easy to find this info, but here we are on SO. Thank you kindly for the CLI command.

Answer (score 22):

To export firestore indexes

```
firebase firestore:indexes > firestore.indexes.json
```

> Caution! This will replace everything in **firestore.indexes.json**.

Or if you have multiple firebase projects in your **.firebaserc**:

```
"projects": {
    "production": "prod-v6909",
    "staging": "prod-c6020"
}
```

Then you can export like this:

```
firebase --project staging firestore:indexes > firestore.indexes.json
```

Comment: Great answer, I could not find information about the export command anywhere in the documentation. (it's missing or at least it's very well hidden)

Answer (score 1):

> You can also list your current Cloud Firestore indexes in JSON from
>   the Firebase CLi: firebase firestore:indexes

For me this when exporting collection group indexes this is exporting a bad formatter json. The command line forget to close the array notifier on indexes:

```
{
  "indexes": [],
  "fieldOverrides": [
    {
      "collectionGroup": "restaurants_users_config",
      "fieldPath": "user",
      "indexes": [
        {
          "order": "ASCENDING",
          "queryScope": "COLLECTION"
        },
        {
          "order": "DESCENDING",
          "queryScope": "COLLECTION"
        },
        {
          "arrayConfig": "CONTAINS",
          "queryScope": "COLLECTION"
        },
        {
          "order": "ASCENDING",
          "queryScope": "COLLECTION_GROUP"
        }
    }
  ]
}
```

Any Suggestions? It is right to only fix the json array by hand?

**edit 
Fix: it was fixed with firebase upgrade 8.2.0 → 8.4.1